# Python Non-ASCII Characters with Encoding Declared

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, utf-8

I'm having an issue with Python2.7 complaining I do not have encoding declared; however, it is infact declared. I'm running this on OS X El Capitan (10.11.3) and python 2.7.11.

I'm attempting to search a data set for specific Chinese and english terms. The report.csv contains the data which I want to search and the raw_terms.txt contains the Chinese and English terms in new line separated. Both files were saved as UTF-8.

I've noticed this code works on different machines, but not mine. I'm assuming there is something I have changed in the year+ I've had this laptop which is causing this issue, but I'm unsure where to start my search.

**Script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import csv

count = 0
with open('./data/report.csv', 'rb') as c:
    csv_data = csv.DictReader(c, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for data in csv_data:
        with open('./terms/raw_terms.txt', 'r') as f:
            for term in f:
                term = term.strip()
                if term in data['Description']: #or term in '你好！你好吗':
                    # print 'Found \"%s\" in \"%s\"' % (term, data['Subject'])
                    count += 1
                else:
                    continue

print count
```

**Error:**

```
File "t.py", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xfe' in file t.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

Appreciate any help/direction anyone can provide.

Comment: You have *not* declared an encoding.  The `coding:` comment applies to your code, not to the file you are opening from the code.  Anyway, the CSV module has well-documented trouble with Unicode -- look for the many, many duplicates here.

Comment: I have tried numerous other techniques including using the `codecs` (`codecs.open(file_location, 'rb', 'UTF-8') as f:`) module and `.encode('unicode-escape')`. Also, it's the non-csv file which I'm getting the error for.

Comment: The error message suggests that your source file has a Unicode BOM, and that it is in fact not in UTF-8.  If it were, the first character would be `\xef`, not `\xfe`.  Probably your file is in UTF-16.  Try to save it as UTF-8 *without* a BOM.

Comment: Thanks @triplee, that's weird. I used Sublime 2 to save the file "with Encoding" > UTF-8. Not including the with BOM option. Any suggestions on how I could save this file properly?

Comment: I have no immediate solution, but a hex dump of the first few bytes of the file may help reveal what exactly you have.

Comment: Ok, very weird. Seems it was the script itself that was erroring; not the files I was attempting to open. "line 1" should have caught my eye. I appreciate you taking the time. I ended up removing `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` and creating a new file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your exception is due to your source code having non-ASCII characters in it. In your case, it appears that your file has been saved as UTF-16 BE with BOM.

Unfortunately, the `encoding` / `coding` header has to come before any non-ascii, which is of course not possible as the BOM has to reside a byte 0. A catch 22 situation.

Your only choice is to change the encoding of your file to an encoding that doesn't need a BOM, such as UTF-8. In Sublime, you can simple choose: File -> Save with Encoding -> UTF-8.

On the command line, you re-encode and strip the BOM:

```
iconv -f UTF-16BE -t UTF-8 test42.py | tail -c +4 > test43.py
```

Also, heed @tripleee's comment about the CSV module in Python 2.x. Instead, use https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv, which is a Unicode compatible drop-in replacement